# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError при запуске Google Maps

Tags: android, карты

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь запустить приложение Google Maps на реальном устройстве.
Но когда запускаю, приложение останавливается.

Лог:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nikiz.googlemaps, PID: 21216
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzah.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4867)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4750)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:179)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nikiz.googlemaps"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nikiz.myapplicationmaps">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MapsActivity.java:

```
package com.example.nikiz.myapplicationmaps;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну выставите свой код разберем

Comment: дело в том, что код самый стандартный, я просто получил API-ключ и вставил его в манифест.
Все остальное - Google Maps Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: а application унаследовать он MultiDexApplication не нужно? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: А вообще, почему так происходит: я создал Google Maps Activity, вставил api-ключ в манифест и просто запустил. В итоге ошибка - `the number of method references in a dex file cannot exceed 64k`. В итоге в dependencies пришлось добавить `multiDexEnabled true`. Почему так происходит?

Comment: @tse не обязательно. Можно просто в манифесте параметр name для application указать. Или переопредить attachBaseContext. Автору виднее, что для него подходит лучше.

Comment: Описание параметра [multiDexEnabled](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) в официальной документации. И [первая же ссылка в Google](https://habrahabr.ru/post/230665/), для тех, кто не может в английский.

Comment: Спасибо большое.
Я переопределил attachBaseContext, но ошибка осталась.

Comment: Опубликуйте манифест и главное активити.

Comment: Так я и думал. Не там переопределили `attachBaseContext`. На сколько я вижу, у вас нет собственной реализации  `android.app.Application`, соответственно, просто добавьте в тег `application` манифеста параметр `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, работает отлично!